# Close all tabs in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've arranged Visual Studio 2010 such that output, error list, find results and many other windows appear in the same "region". I don't know if that's the correct term, they appear as tabs next to each other.
Is there a way to close all these windows at the same time, preferable a keyboard shortcut?

Edit:
About the possible duplicate here: [Close all tool windows in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388746/close-all-tool-windows-in-visual-studio).
That is a pretty close question, and I didn't see it before posting. There is a difference though, I only want to close all windows inside a particular "region" not the solution explorer or properties. However I guess it should be possible to modify the macro from the answer:

```
Public Sub CloseAllToolWindows()
Dim items As EnvDTE.Windows = DTE.Windows
Dim item As Window

   For Each item In items
        If item.Kind = "Tool" And item.Visible And Not item.IsFloating And _
           item.Caption <> "Solution Explorer" And _
           item.Caption <> "Properties" And _
           item.Caption <> "To-do Explorer" And _
           item.Caption <> "Macro Explorer" Then
            item.Close()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close all tool windows in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388746/close-all-tool-windows-in-visual-studio)

Comment: No, there isn't such a command built in. It only exists for *document* windows. You'll have to write a macro and assign it to a keyboard shortcut if you want to automate this.

Comment: Hi I don't think it's duplicate. I've updated my question...

Answer (score 170):

Go to `Window -> Close All Documents`

The shortcut is `ALT W+L`

Comment: How you found this? It just works but ehy, it's not write anywhere!

Comment: Also works: `CTRL+K, CTRL+W` (At least in Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: @Cirelli94It is, Alt + W opens up the "Window" context menu at the top, and the "l" hits the "Close All Documents" option in that context menu, which you can see because there's an underlined "l", telling you hitting "l" will press that option.

Comment: Works on VS Code also.

Answer (score 68):

These are the best keyboard shortcuts when you work with tabs:

**Close All Documents**

- Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>
- MacOs: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

**Close Current Documents**

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>
- MacOs: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

**Close All But This** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>

**Open Containing Folder** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>

**Copy Full Path** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>

**Pin Tab** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>

**Float Tab** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>

**Auto Hide All Tab** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>

*any shortcuts that you need just comment it...*

Comment: For Mac, the Close All But This command is `Command + Alt + T`. And if you want to customize it into your own command, try to adjust the key in `keybindings.json`, the command is `workbench.action.closeOtherEditors`. Here is how. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Comment: Also useful, `Ctrl` + `[`, `S` - Locate current file in Solution Explorer, if Track Active Item is disabled.

Answer (score 62):

Right click on one of the tabs, select "Close all but this", then close the last one the normal way.
Its not optimal but its far less work than closing each and everyone.

Edit: this only works for open files. Not error list, output or such. My bad...

Edit: In Visual Studio 2013 Preview you can now right click on any open document tab and select *Close All Documents*

Comment: You might be interested in Window | Close All Documents.

Comment: Note for VS Code (I realize this is not for Code, but this comes up when searching)
Right-click a tab, there is a close all tabs option, shortcut (Ctrl-K-W).

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use KB shortcut, you can right click a tab and choose close all.

Answer (score 5):

No. You don't need Visual Studio 2013 as other post. You go to this to re-define your hotkey:

```
Tools >> Options >> Keyboard
```

Type : `Window.CloseAll` in `Show Command Containing`.  You will see a line : `Windows.CloseAllDocuments` . Double click into it.

At textbox Press shortcut keys : type shortcut you want for this hotkey.
At drop down list on the left, choose `Text Editor`. Press Assign.

Repeat above step, but at drop down list, you choose : `Global`

Press OK

Now, each time you press the shortcut you have defined, all tabs will be close.

Help this help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Unselect Tools | Options | Environment | General | Close Button affects active tab only.

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyboard shortcut in mac to close all tabs:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for mac

Answer (score 0):

**FOR Windows PC**

**Ctrl k, Ctrl W:** Close All tabs (First press Ctrl K simultaneously, then press Ctrl W Simultaneously)

**Ctrl K:** Close Current Tab