# Visual Studio 2013 close all Tool Windows

Tags: automation, autohotkey, visual-studio-2013

I would be delighted, elated even, if someone could tell me how to close every tool window in Visual Studio 2013 in an automatable fasion. Solution Explorer, Output Window, and Toolbox are all examples of the countless tool windows that can accumulate on my screen. I'm using Autohotkey to try to close them, but it has become impossible to do through blind keyboard shortcuts (AFIK.)
I'm not opposed to a plugin but something with just the keyboard would be ideal.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have a look at `WinClose`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388746/close-all-tool-windows-in-visual-studio and use Visual Commander to run the macro.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about Visual Commander. I used to be all about the macros. I try to do everything with AutoHotkey now, but this might save my bacon some day. Props to MCL for getting in quick and putting us on the right track. I needed more inspiration to try detaching the windows. Go team! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with Autohotkey, take a look at [WinClose](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) as MCL suggested. You might also need [SetTitleMatchMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm).
I'm still using Visual Studio 2010, but with some minor adjustments it should also work in Visual Studio 2012:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;No need to enter the full title
Enter:: ;press enter to close all tool windows
    WinClose, Microsoft Visual, Find and Replace
    WinClose, Microsoft Visual, Solution Explorer
    WinClose, Microsoft Visual, Class View
    WinClose, Microsoft Visual, Property Manager
    ;...
    Sleep, 1000
Return

Esc:: ;Use Esc to exit the script
  ExitApp
```

Use "AU3_Spy.exe" form your Autohotkey folder to find the WinTitle(part) and some visible text.

Comment: This is getting interesting. Thanks for your post Forivin! Here's the trouble. This will work (unless I'm missing something) only if you have the tool windows detached from the main window. It turns out that will probably work. I've got 3 monitors at my new job.

Comment: Yes, you definitely have to detach the windows to make this work.. If you want to close them even if they are attached things are getting very complicated. The only thing I can think of here is using imagesearch or pixelsearch to check if the windows exist and mouseclicks to close them. This would be pretty complicated though..

Answer (score 1):

Layouts-O-Rama is my take on the problem. To be found in the vs gallery here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c

Basically the addin saves tool window layouts. You could simply save a layout with all tool windows closed and assign a hotkey to it. To go even further you could save another layout with all the tool windows you like opened and assign a different hotkey to this.

Comment: I have tried out Layouts-O-Rama a bit and it appears to be my Holy Grail. I am beyond impressed with how well it seems to work. A big thanks to @mklein for sharing this! I have literally wanted something like this for a decade and have tried with varying levels of terrible results to achieve something like it.